# uses for dynamic scope?

Tags: lisp, scope, elisp

I've been getting my hands wet with emacs lisp, and one thing that trips me up sometimes is the dynamic scope. Is there much of a future for it? Most languages I know use static scoping (or have moved to static scoping, like Python), and probably because I know it better I tend to prefer it. Are there specific applications/instances or examples where dynamic scope is more useful?

Comment: Lots of [useful answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321000/dynamic-scoping-why) - perhaps this is close enough to be a duplicate?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a good discussion of this issue [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DynamicBindingVsLexicalBinding). The most useful part that pertains to your question is:

> Dynamic bindings are great for
>   modifying the behaviour of subsystems.
>   Suppose you are using a function ‘foo’
>   that generates output using ‘print’.
>   But sometimes you would like to
>   capture the output in a buffer of your
>   choosing. With dynamic binding, it’s
>   easy:

```
(let ((b (generate-new-buffer-name " *string-output*"))))
    (let ((standard-output b))
      (foo))
    (set-buffer b)
    ;; do stuff with the output of foo
    (kill-buffer b))
```

> (And if you used this kind of thing a
>   lot, you’d encapsulate it in a macro –
>   but luckily it’s already been done as
>   ‘with-output-to-temp-buffer’.)
>
> This works because ‘foo’ uses the
>   dynamic binding of the name
>   ‘standard-output’, so you can
>   substitute your own binding for that
>   name to modify the behaviour of ‘foo’
>   – and of all the functions that ‘foo’
>   calls.
>
> In a language without dynamic binding,
>   you’d probably add an optional
>   argument to ‘foo’ to specify a buffer
>   and then ‘foo’ would pass that to any
>   calls to ‘print’. But if ‘foo’ calls
>   other functions which themselves call
>   ‘print’ you’ll have to alter those
>   functions as well. And if ‘print’ had
>   another option, say ‘print-level’,
>   you’d have to add that as an optional
>   argument as well… Alternatively, you
>   could remember the old value of
>   ‘standard-output’, substitute your new
>   value, call ‘foo’ and then restore the
>   old value. And remember to handle
>   non-local exits using ‘throw’. When
>   you’re through with this, you’ll see
>   that you’ve implemented dynamic
>   binding!

That said, lexical binding is IMHO much better for 99% of the cases. Note that modern Lisps are not dynamic-binding-only like Emacs lisp.

- Common Lisp supports both forms of binding, though the lexical one is used much more
- The Scheme specification doesn't even specify dynamic binding (only lexical one), though many implementations support both.

In addition, modern languages like Python and Ruby that were somewhat inspired by Lisp usually support lexical-binding in a straightforward way, with dynamic binding also available but less straightforward.

Answer (score 7):

If you read the [Emacs paper](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-paper.html) (written in 1981), there's a specific section ["Language Features for Extensibility"](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-paper.html#SEC15) that addresses this question.  In Emacs, there's also the added scope of buffer-local (file local) variables.

I've quoted the most relevant portion below:

> [Formal Parameters Cannot Replace
>   Dynamic Scope](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-paper.html#SEC18)
>
> Some language designers believe that
>   dynamic binding should be avoided, and
>   explicit argument passing should be
>   used instead. Imagine that function A
>   binds the variable FOO, and calls the
>   function B, which calls the function
>   C, and C uses the value of FOO.
>   Supposedly A should pass the value as
>   an argument to B, which should pass it
>   as an argument to C.
>
> This cannot be done in an extensible
>   system, however, because the author of
>   the system cannot know what all the
>   parameters will be. Imagine that the
>   functions A and C are part of a user
>   extension, while B is part of the
>   standard system. The variable FOO does
>   not exist in the standard system; it
>   is part of the extension. To use
>   explicit argument passing would
>   require adding a new argument to B,
>   which means rewriting B and everything
>   that calls B. In the most common case,
>   B is the editor command dispatcher
>   loop, which is called from an awful
>   number of places.
>
> What's worse, C must also be passed an
>   additional argument. B doesn't refer
>   to C by name (C did not exist when B
>   was written). It probably finds a
>   pointer to C in the command dispatch
>   table. This means that the same call
>   which sometimes calls C might equally
>   well call any editor command
>   definition. So all the editing
>   commands must be rewritten to accept
>   and ignore the additional argument. By
>   now, none of the original system is
>   left!

Comment: Excellent quote! This is really an excellent example of how dynamic binding is useful. Thanks for sharing!